# what is the opposite of pushviewcontroller in iphone?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

I m working on one project in which I m calling other viewcontroller in the below way:--

```
AppDelegate *app2 = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:app2.SecondForm animated:NO];
app2 =nil;
```

My application is navigation based and in which I have created my on back button on navigation bar

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarStyleBlackOpaque target:self action:@selector(Back:)];
}
```

in this way my Back action will call on click

```
-(IBAction)Back:(id)sender
{
     // What code I will write over here to get the same functionality
     // which is by default given by navigation controller?
}
```

Comment: NO No I want to call my other view in same way but in place of navigation button I replaced with my Back button

Answer (score 7):

I think you are looking for:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 4):

popViewControllerAnimated

Comment: NO No I want to call my other view in same way but in place of navigation button I replaced that navigation button which i generated automatically with  my Back button and get the same functionality that is given by automatic navigation button